# Create and "Save As" text file automatically using PHP

Tags: php, text-files

So, I am trying to export some data from a database and have it automatically prompt the user to save the data has a text file. Here is my code:

```
$dateFile = rand(10000000, 99999999).".txt";
$dataString = "My data here blah blah blah";
$fWrite = fopen($dateFile,"w");
$wrote = fwrite($fWrite, $dataString);
fclose($fWrite);
header('Content-Type: application/text');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$dateFile);
```

This seems to work in small ways - the text file is, indeed, being created in the same directory (as the PHP page), and the file seems to open... but with no data in it. If I navigate to the text file and open it, then I can see my string there. It just doesn't open with the file automatically. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: FWIW I don't actually need the file to be saved to the server *per se*, I just thought that this would be a quick and easy way of getting a "Save As" text file created... if anyone can think of a way of doing this without saving anything to the server, that is good, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried sending the content directly?

```
header('Content-Type: application/text');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$dateFile.'"');
echo $dataString;
```

It's maybe a simple way, but might be the solution you need.

Comment: Actually... that's terrific! thank you. Just what I wanted. :)

Comment: Happy to help :) please mark it as the correct answer if you think that it is ;-)

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```
$dateFile = rand(10000000, 99999999).".txt";
$dataString = "My data here blah blah blah";
file_put_contents($dateFile,$dataString) 
header('Content-Type: application/text');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$dateFile);
echo file_get_contents($dateFile);
```

Answer (score -1):

you have to call the [Flush][1] Method to write the buffer to the file:

[Greetz](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php)